# Excel does not calculate after using POI (Java)

Tags: java, vba, excel, apache-poi

recently I started working with POI. Now I have a problem. After updating my cell values with POI my excel workbook does not calculate with the new values. 
The new values are displayed in Excel but won't be used for the calculation.
I have to click on the formula again, press enter so that the calculation works. 
Pressing F9 does not work for me.
Now I am looking for a solution so that Excel or Java refreshes every formula.
Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Alt + f9... Or `Application.Calculate`... Or `Application.CalculateFull`.

Comment: Are you doing a Formula Evaluation with Apache POI when you're done updating all your cells?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Recalculation+of+Formulas

Comment: @alex thanks just forgot this. Its working now.